# zabbix-docker docker-compose.yml understanding

Tags: docker, zabbix

Im trying to run a zabbix server to monitor all my docker containers.

I have downloaded the github from https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix-docker.

I have tried to use the https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix-docker/blob/6.0/docker-compose_v3_alpine_mysql_latest.yaml

I ve seen there is a sqlite proxy service but i dont know how to configure it so the server runs on sqlite?
Which services should i keep so it runs well on sqlite? I guess i can get rid of apache and nginx?

I have tried to look at the depends_on sections but the zabbix-server service depends on    mysql-server, so i dont see how to run it on the zabbix-proxy-sqlite3 service.

I have tried to look for documentation but the wiki only gives docker related documentation and say the docker-compose.yml files are overloaded.

thank you

best regards

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to configure it so the server runs on sqlite?

Zabbix server does not support sqlite. [Zabbix **proxy**](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/it/manual/concepts/proxy) supports sqlite. It's not a proxy for sqlite, it's zabbix proxy service running using sqlite database.

I am not aware of the reasoning, but do not install such a big service with sqlite, it's too big. Use a real database.

Comment: ok thanks. but does the zabbix server works correctly without the zabbix proxy? can i get rid of all the proxy related services in docker-compose?

Comment: Yes. Zabbix proxy is for monitoring stuff unreachable by zabbix server. You don't need it. I believe that information should be easily available from documentation

Comment: ok thanks, so  can I also get rid of zabbix-java-gateway and zabbix-snmptraps on which zabbix proxy depend ?

Comment: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/items/itemtypes/snmptrap https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/concepts/java That just depends on the functionality you want... normally no, you don't, just the server.

Comment: i ve read the docs and it's still unclear what snmp traps and java do. zabbix is supposed to monitor my docker containers. but zabbix server, snmp traps and java all do monitoring so what am i supposed to do?! the doc is so bad at specifying what is doing what...

Comment: `what snmp traps` thing to monitor switches, see wiki `java do` see zabbix java documentation `zabbix is supposed to monitor my docker containers` than you do not need snmp traps and you do not need java. `what am i supposed to do?` install zabbix-server, install grafana, install gradana zabbix plugin, install zabbix docker template, start monitoring.